# Magento 1.9.3.4 PDF uploads not working in WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: php, xml, magento, pdf, magento-1.9

In the WYSIWYG editor, PDF uploads do not work. I get the error message "Invalid MIME type". I have tried several methods in order to fix this such as editing th app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml file with

```
    <allowed>
      <jpg>1</jpg>
      <jpeg>1</jpeg>
      <png>1</png>
      <gif>1</gif>
      <pdf>1</pdf>
    </allowed>
```

I have also added the pdf section in the media_allowed and image_allowed xml elements to no avail. Furthermore, I have installed an extension called "Lanot file manager" but that returns the same error - "Invalid MIME type". Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

At first: Please do not change core files! Your changes will be lost with every update.

You need to allow pdf also as "allowed_images"-type.

You can try this module: https://github.com/hhirsch/magento_pdf_upload